# Analytic solution to differential equation for fermions

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, special-functions

In this paper [FermionicOperators](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0607205.pdf), the author solved the following D.E (see eq.($33$)) in the paper

$$\Bigg(\partial_r^2 + \frac{6}{r} \partial_r + \frac{1}{r^2}(-|m_l|^2 R^2 + 6 + |m_l| ~ R ~ \gamma^r) ~ + \frac{M^2 R^4}{(r^2 + L^2)^2} \Bigg) ~ f_l(r) = 0$$

analytically and the solution is given in terms of the hypergeometric function in the very generic form $F(a,b,c,-r^2/L^2)$ with a,b,c some constants that are defined (see eq.($34$) in the link given above).

Some useful relations taken from the same paper, and relevant to solving the above D.E are $\gamma^r = \pm 1$ and $m_l$ can take to values but I am only interested in the following $m_l = \frac{5}{2} + l$. Finally, $R$ can be set to one.

I wanted to solve the D.E and this is what I wrote down.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
DSolve[D[f[r], {r, 2}] + 6/r D[f[r], r] - 1/r^2 (5/2 + l)^2 f[r] + 
   6 f[r] - (5/2 + l) f[r] + M^2/(r^2 + L^2)^2 f[r] == 0, f[r], r]
```

The result that Mathematica returns is in terms of differential roots.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions as to what could be done?

Some more comments.

Intuition from studying the corresponding equation for scalars is actually telling me that the solution should be a combination of hypergeometrics.

The equation for scalar modes is (see eq.($7$) in the given link)

$$\partial_{\rho}^2 f(\rho) + \frac{3}{\rho} \partial_{\rho} f(\rho) + \Bigg(\frac{M^2}{\rho^2 + L^2} - \frac{l(l+2)}{\rho^2}\Bigg)f(\rho) = 0$$

The code is

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
DSolve[D[f[r], {r, 2}] + 3/r D[f[r], r] + 
     M^2/(r^2 + L^2)^2 f[r] - (l (l + 2))/r^2 f[r] == 0, f[r], r] // 
  Factor // FullSimplify
```

which Mathematica solves analytically, and the solution is given as a sum of two hypergeometrics, and after imposing normalisation conditions and some quantisation conditions, one can obtain the result that is given in the paper. (the procedure is better described in the seminal paper for the scalars, but I have verified and solved the relations there. The main point is that even I do not employ the sophisticated trick for the scalars to solve the D.E and I do a brute force caclulation, I get a result which I can manipulate.)

P.S: To avoid confusion, I am not asking that anyone of you can come up with a mathematical trick or a physical argument to make the D.E more elegant. I am just asking, if anyone can suggest some tips or modifications in the code to do the stupid thing. Take a relation given in a paper and obtain some analytic solutions.

Comment: try Maple for first one, it gives solution in terms of HuenC special functions.![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EfBDY.png)  I do not think Mathematica supports HuenC special functions last time I looked.

Comment: Thank you @Nasser. Really appreciate it. Cheers!!!